# Can't use Type in VB

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Is there anything wrong with the following code ? It failed on `Form_Load()` line , and complains about it.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Type Human
        Name As String
    End Type

    Dim stu As Student
    With Human:
        .Name = "Someone"
    End With

    Debug.Print ("Name: " & stu.Name)

End Sub
```

Comment: You can do better than "complains about it"

Comment: Type keyword is not supported in VB.NET. VB.NET uses Structure keyword - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/55yzhfb2(v=vs.80).aspx and VB6 struct - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/030kb3e9(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

#### 1

Create a new class

```
Private Class Human
    Public Name As String
End Class
```

(Obviously it would be better to wrap the Name in a public property, but for simplicity, exposing it as a public variable is easier.)

#### 2

Create a new struct:

```
Structure Human
    Dim Name As String
End Structure
```

**Note**
It should be noted that *both* of these options must be done outside of the function, not within Form_Load function

Answer (score 0):

The keyword is no longer Type; it is Structure now. Type was used in VB6 and earlier, but not in .NET.